# DB2 Express-c v10.1: где находится Control Center?

Tags: db2, ibm, база-данных

DB2 Express-c v10.1, не могу найти Control Center (далее СС). Устанавливал с официального сайта [ibm.com](http://ibm.com). Установил следующие пакеты:

-`DB2 Express-C db2_v101_winx64_expc.exe`
-`Data Studio Administration Client ibm_data_studio_standalone_win_V311.zip`

Прежде всего не нашел СС в корне, где установлена DB2, а также не нашел вызвав командой в командной строке: db2cc.Помогите разобраться. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db2cc убран начиная с версии 9.7 ЕМНИП, пользуйтесь IBM Data Studio 3.1.1

Comment: уже ковыряю, как то с СС удобнее было. спасибо за ответ.

Comment: пожалуйста. я еще на 9ке дата студию попользовал, на винде оно понравилось больше, чем поднятие на винде xserver'a чтобы пользовать ее, поскольку серв с базой gui-less =)

Comment: а я только начал изучать:) а можете посмотреть мой вопрос про SQL=0104N.

Comment: посмотрел, ответил, но както программированием не занимался под db2, занимался чтобы работало и бекапилось автоматически, остальным управляла 1с :)